# Simulink: Convert Continuous Signal to Discrete

Tags: signal-processing, simulink, discrete-mathematics, data-acquisition

I am very new to simulink, so this question may seem simple. I am looking for a way to sample a continuous signal every X number of seconds.

essentially what I am doing is simulating the principle of a data acquisition unit for a demonstration I am running, but I can't seem to find a block to do this, the nearest thing I can get is the Zero-Order-Hold.

Comment: Would you sketch what you have tried so far and how it didn't meet your expectations?

Answer (score 5):

What you may need is a combination of two blocks. First, a Quantizer block to discretize the input to a chosen resolution. Second a Zero-Order Hold block to sample and hold at the chosen sampling rate.

The ordering doesn't seem to be of much importance here.

Here's an example:
[image: Simple Sampling Model]

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use the **Rate Transition** block.
[image]

[image]